# What is the name of the pronunciation symbol /o/ with a dot over it?

Tags: single-word-requests, pronunciation, symbols

What is the name of the pronunciation symbol /o/ with a dot over it?  We know it is pronounced /aw/ but need to know what the name of the symbol is.

Comment: try drawing it in [shapecatcher](http://shapecatcher.com/)

Comment: We may need more information. [IPA](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/8/8f/IPA_chart_%28C%292005.pdf) doesn't appear to use dots as diacritics to produce something like **ȯ**. There is a letter ö but that's not really pronounced /ɔ/. And there is /ʘ/ but that's a *bilabial click*.

Comment: Please understand that whatever your ***ȯ*** is intended to mean, it is not a standard phonetic symbol the way ***ɔ*** is.

Answer (score 1):

If it says *aw* as in *aww*, then it is an **open o**, written as /ɔ/.